# I would like to set up Devise forgot password email with Amazons (ActionMailer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, devise

I am trying to set up the reset password emails for devise but my project uses amazon not the default mailer in ruby. How can i go about changing this?

Thanks!

UPDATE

I have connected the AmazonMailer using `config.mailer = "AmazonMailer"`  now this is what my mailer looks like

```
class AmazonMailer < Devise::Mailer

  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.

  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`

  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views 

    # require 'sendgrid-ruby'
    # include SendGrid

    # def send_email(subject, body, to_email, from_email)

    #   from = Email.new(email: "#{from_email}")
    #   to = Email.new(email: "#{to_email}")
    #   content = Content.new(type: 'text/html', value: "#{body}")

    #   mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

    #   personalization = Personalization.new
    #   personalization.to = to
    #       #personalization.custom_args = CustomArg.new(key: obj_type, value: obj_id)
    #       mail.personalizations = personalization

    #       puts mail.to_json

    #       sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'] || '[EXPOSED API KEY]', host: 'https://api.sendgrid.com')
    #       response = sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
    #       puts response.status_code
    #       puts response.body
    #       puts response.headers
    #   end


    require 'aws-sdk'
    require 'json'

    # Overrides same inside Devise::Mailer
    def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
        

    end


    def self.send_email(subject, body, from_name, from_email, to_email, source)
        
    client = Aws::SES::Client.new

        resp = client.send_email({
            destination: {
                bcc_addresses: [], 
                cc_addresses: [], 
                to_addresses: [to_email]
            }, 
            message: {
                body: {
                    html: {
                            charset: "UTF-8", 
                            data: body
                            }, 
                    text: {
                            charset: "UTF-8", 
                            data: ""
                        } 
                    }, 
                subject: {
                            charset: "UTF-8", 
                            data: subject
                        } 
                    }, 
            reply_to_addresses: [from_email], 
            #return_path: "", 
            #return_path_arn: "", 
            source: source, 
            #source_arn: ""
            })

        resp['message_id'] unless !resp && !resp['message_id']
    end
end
```

inside my mailer I would like to override the `reset_password_instructions` method to send from Amazon and not the default.

Comment: What Amazon Web Service are you using to send email? And how did you set it up to replace ActionMailer?

Comment: Hey @Leito thanks for the response. I am using SES and i already changed  the mailer and parent mailer in the devise.rb using config.mailer = 'AmazonMailer' what is left is sending my own email. I am adding an update to the question check it out,

Comment: If you are sending all your emails through SES, why not configure ActionMailer to connect to SES using SMTP? Here is a guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-an-email-using-smtp.html. That way, you don't have to change anything on the mailers, just use them as you normally would.

Comment: @Leito no changes would need to be made to the devise?

Comment: By [default](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.3.0/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L21) `DeviseMailer` inherits from `ActionMailer::Base`. So as long as you configure your entire application to use SES through SMTP, no further changes are needed, you (and Devise) simply send emails the Rails way.